How to ignore a specific prefix at the beginning if exsits and match the rest
I need to write a regex that ignores the specific string "YGXZYY" at the beginning if present, and then match all the rest, For example:

String: "YGXZYY zhang san san" return the matched result: "zhang san san"

string: "chang san san" return the matched result: "chang san san"

string: "GXZYY zhang san san" return the matched result: "zhang san san"


because the regex expression is entered from the UI actually, so I don't have any change for pre-processing or just extract the text I need by capture group, that means I need an entire matched result.
So the match logic code in C# would be:
 public static void DebugPrefix()
 {
     string input1 = "YGXZYY zhang san san";  // should be: zhang san san
     string input2 = "chang san san";  // should be: chang san san
     string input3 = "GXZYY zhang san san";  // should be: GXZYY zhang san san        

     var samples = new List<string>
     {
         input1,
         input2,
         input3                             
     };

     string pattern = @"(?(^YGXZYY)(?<=^YGXZYY)[a-zA-Z\s]+|[a-zA-Z\s]+)";
     //pattern = @"(?<=^YGXZYY)[a-zA-Z\s]+|(?<!^YGXZYY)[a-zA-Z\s]+";
     pattern = @"(?<!YGXZYY)[a-zA-Z\s]+";           
     Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

     for (int idx = 0; idx < samples.Count; idx++)
     {
         var input = samples[idx];
         var result = regex.Match(input);
         Console.WriteLine($"sample {idx + 1}, origin string:{input}, matched result:{result.Value}");
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
 }

I think it should combine conditional expression and look behind features to work it out,
I read a lot of articles but I failed to make it work.

try this @"^(?:YGXZYY\s+)?(.+)"

the question is unclear. if you just wanted to remove YGXZYY at the very beginning of the string (followed by any number of whitespaces) it would be enough Regex.Replace(input, @"^YGXZYY\s*", ""); ... but it's unclear what you meant when you said because the regex expression is entered from the UI actually

Perhaps like this (?<=^YGXZYY\s+)[a-zA-Z].* see https://regex101.com/r/W4Soou/1 or (?<=^YGXZYY\s+)[a-zA-Z].*|^(?!YGXZYY\s)[a-zA-Z].* see https://regex101.com/r/cHTmlt/1

@HezyZiv thanks, but this rule is failed for example input1.

Hi @DiegoD, to be clear, I means that the code for testing  I show above which the match logic is actually from the client software, so I couldn't write my custom code with Regex.Replace or something like matched.Groups[1].Value. What I could only provide is an regex rule text.

@Thefourthbird, Thanks a lot. The second rule works for all examples!  I will do research on it.

@WeiTao Great, in that case you can accept the posted answer by Wiktor.

By matching ^(?:YGXZYY *)?(.*) (which is certain to match), your substring of interest will be contained in capture group 1. Demo. The regex optionally (?) matches 'YGXZYY' at the beginning of the string followed by zero or more spaces, that possible match followed by the remainder of the string which is captured in group 1 ((.*)).

@WeiTao If all your strings start with a word character, also this idea: \b(?!^YGXZYY)\w.*

You can use
public static void DebugPrefix()
{
    string input1 = "YGXZYY zhang san san";  // should be: zhang san san
    string input2 = "chang san san";  // should be: chang san san
    string input3 = "GXZYY zhang san san";  // should be: GXZYY zhang san san        

    var samples = new List<string>
    {
        input1,
        input2,
        input3                             
    };

    string pattern = @"(?<=^YGXZYY\s+).+|^(?!YGXZYY\s).+";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < samples.Count; idx++)
    {
        var input = samples[idx];
        var result = regex.Match(input)?.Groups[2].Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"sample {idx + 1}, origin string:{input.Value}, matched result:{result}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

See the C# demo. Output:
sample 1, origin string:YGXZYY zhang san san, matched result:zhang san san
sample 2, origin string:chang san san, matched result:chang san san
sample 3, origin string:GXZYY zhang san san, matched result:GXZYY zhang san san

The (?<=^YGXZYY\s+).+|^(?!YGXZYY\s).+ regex pattern matches

(?<=^YGXZYY\s+).+ - any one or more chars other than LF chars as many as possible that ARE preceded by YGXZYY text at the start of the string
|- or
^(?!YGXZYY\s).+ - any one or more chars other than LF chars as many as possible that do not start with the YGXZYY text at the start of the string.


The C# code I show in question is the underlying logic that I am unable to modify(I get this logic code by decompiling the assembly and just write some example for testing),  what I could do is just providing an regex rule text in the input control. So the method by accessing capture group is unavailable. (￣Д ￣)

@WeiTao OK, see the update.
